# Can someone please make a tag 'apache-http-client' on stackoverflow?

Tags: support, status-declined, stack-overflow, tags

This tag would pertain to questions relating to http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

thanks,
David.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the [httpclient](/questions/tagged/httpclient) tag is been used for that. While "apache" is not explicitly mentioned, practically all questions with that tag refers to the Apache HttpClient. I've retagged [your SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612573/exception-using-httprequest-execute-invalid-use-of-singleclientconnmanager-co) with that. To get better attendance (users usually browse questions by tags), I've added the [java](/questions/tagged/java) main tag as well.